# Como montar uma lista com os dados de um Observable?

Tags: firebase, typescript, arraylist, angular, ionic3

### Como percorrer os dados de um Observable e inserir em uma lista?

Gostaria de montar uma lista com todos os arrays que contém dentro do **Observable** que vem do **Cloud Firestore**, pois preciso de uma lista com as pessoas para exibir em **MatTableDataSource**.

```
export interface Pessoa {
     nome: string;
     cidade: string;
}

    export MyClass {
        list_pessoa: Pessoa[] = [];
        pessoa: Observable<Pessoa[]>;

        constructor(){

    // Algo parecido como isso, mas que funcione!
    this.pessoa.forEach(v =>{
      const d = v.values()
      this.list_pessoa.push(d);
    })

    console.log(this.list_pessoa);

}
}
```

**Saída:** 
list_pessoa [ 
{'nome': 'pessoa1', 'cidade': 'cidade1'},
{'nome': 'pesssoa2', 'cidade': 'cidade2'}
]

---

- Qual a melhor forma de percorrer os dados que estão dentro do
  **Observable** e inserir em uma lista de arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a iteração se inscrevendo para a resposta do Observable assim:

```
export interface Pessoa {
     nome: string;
     cidade: string;
}

export MyClass {
    list_pessoa: Pessoa[] = [];
    pessoa: Observable<Pessoa[]>;

    constructor(){

    this.pessoa
     .subscribe(res => this.list_pessoa = res);

    console.log(this.list_pessoa);
    }
}
```

Método de retorno:

```
  getPessoas() {

    this.pessoasCol = this.afs.collection('pessoas', ref => ref.orderBy('nome', 'asc'));

    this.pessoas = this.pessoasCol.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Pessoa;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });

    return this.pessoas;
  }
```

A chamada do método é feita da seguinte forma:

```
this.pessoa = this.providerPessoa.getPessoas();
```

Comment: Olá Arnaldo, agradeço desde já a intenção de querer ajudar mas não esta retornando nada do Observable usando subscribe, de uma olhada acima no método que retorna o Observable caso for preciso.

Answer (score -1):

Para percorrer os dados de um **Observable** e inserir em uma lista, você pode usar o método **subscribe()** do Observable e implementar um callback que receberá os dados do **Observable**. Então, dentro deste **callback**, você pode iterar sobre os dados e adicioná-los à sua lista. Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Pessoa } from './pessoa.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `{{list_pessoa | json}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  list_pessoa: Pessoa[] = [];
  pessoa: Observable<Pessoa[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.pessoa.subscribe((data: Pessoa[]) => {
      data.forEach((pessoa: Pessoa) => {
        this.list_pessoa.push(pessoa);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Neste **exemplo**, o método **subscribe()** recebe um callback que recebe os dados do **Observable** pessoa. Dentro deste **callback**, nós iteramos sobre os dados e adicionamos cada pessoa à nossa lista **list_pessoa**. Note que **subscribe()** é chamado uma única vez na inicialização do componente. A saída esperada é uma lista de **objetos** Pessoa.

Uma forma comum de percorrer os dados de um **Observable** e inseri-los em uma lista de arrays é usando o operador **subscribe()** do **Observable**.

Veja um **exemplo** de como fazer isso:

```
export interface Pessoa {
  nome: string;
  cidade: string;
}

export class MyClass {
  list_pessoa: Pessoa[] = [];
  pessoa: Observable<Pessoa[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.pessoa = db.collection<Pessoa>('pessoas').valueChanges();
    this.pessoa.subscribe(pessoas => {
      this.list_pessoa = pessoas;
    });
  }
}
```

Nesse exemplo, é feita uma consulta à coleção "**pessoas**" do **Cloud Firestore** usando o método **valueChanges()** do **AngularFirestore**, que retorna um **Observable** contendo as pessoas da coleção. O operador **subscribe()** é usado para percorrer os dados do Observable e atribuí-los à lista **list_pessoa**. O código acima assume que você já tem uma instância do **AngularFirestore** injetada em sua classe.